# Laravel 5.1 custom model does not generate a table

Tags: model, laravel-5.1

I am Laravel beginner and I want to create a custom Model. After running artisan make command, docs say following :

> Note that we did not tell Eloquent which table to use for our User
>   model. The "snake case", plural name of the class will be used as the
>   table name unless another name is explicitly specified.

But when and how is the table created? When I use `->save()` method to store my stuff in DB, I Assumed, the table will be automatically created if Laravel cant find such table. Instead, I got Missing Table Error.

Does it suppose, i need to have created table using migration BEFORE creating of Model? Any help appreciated. So far, i read all the docs about custom Models, but i cant get answer i need.

Comment: You need to [run a migration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations) first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the table before Model from migration file check Documentation **[Creating tables](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#creating-tables)** section, then the model will use the plural name of the class as the table name.

**NOTE :** You have to set up your database configuration firstly and create database manually check **[Database: Getting Started](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/database#accessing-connections)** section.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. AT this time i already made a migration. Looks like even creating a custom model using artisan will create a migration php file, which already needs to be modified and launched using php artisan migrate command.